# How do I format my array properly?

Tags: java, arrays

So i have an arraylist that looks like this: (1 Letter + lineseperator)

[image: picture]

I need it to be like a table that looks like this
[image: picture1]

I know that I can format an array with

```
formatedString = anArray.toString()
    .replace(",", "")
    .replace("[", "")
    .replace("]", "");
```

and Stuff but I dont know how to get it into that table position then.

So thats what I did to create the Arrays:

// All "letterAnzahl" are just counters that are defining how many as and bs there are.

```
while (eAnzahl < fAnzahl) {
          undbed1.add("a" + newLine); // adds it to array
          eAnzahl++;
        } 
        
        do {
          undbed1.add("b" + newLine);
          hAnzahl++;
        } while (hAnzahl < fAnzahl);
       

        do { // not important at all
          var = var - var2;  
          iAnzahl++;          
        } while (iAnzahl < fAnzahl); 
        
        eAnzahl = 0;
        hAnzahl = 0;
        hAnzahl = 0;
      } // Ende des if else  
    } while (var > 0);
    
    formatedString = undbed1.toString()
    .replace(",", "")
    .replace("[", "")
    .replace("]", "");
    undbed2.add(formatedString);
   
    gAnzahl++;
    
    undbed1.clear();         // Clears 1. array to start over
    formatedString = "";   
    
    fAnzahl = fAnzahl * 2; 
   
    var = var + var1;
    var2 = var2 * 2;
    
  } while (dAnzahl >= gAnzahl);
```

Depending on the inputs you gave the program further above you end up with a really long array. (Picture 1)

Im extremely new to java so please dont hate on my if i did something really stupid

Comment: Remove the newlines and then print the arrays line by line

Comment: Once you share what you've tried, can someone help you here.

Comment: Is all the string in your array are equisized?

Comment: @UnholySheep added code

Comment: @fafl i dont think that would work

Comment: Why are you keeping the data in an array *with formatting*? That's exactly what causes the problem. You should keep only the data itself (the letter), and add formatting (newlines, spaces, tabs) when you need to print it, in whatever format.

Comment: In the first array everything looks like this: a,b,a,b,a,b. After formatting it it is like ababab and as you can see its a whileloop so it starts over again and and that would make the array longer but wouldnt solve my problem at all. still cant format the way i need it @RealSkeptic

Comment: The best I can guess is that it is an ArrayList of Strings. You keep referring to the String as array. Without the line separators, your **ArrayList** would look like this:  **["abababab", "aabbaabb", "aaaabbbb"]**. This list of strings can be easily formatted into the ouput you want. As RealSkeptic said, you shouldn't keep newlines, spaces, etc in your string. Add them when you print them. It's easier that way

Answer (score 0):

I don't get your problem. Please tell me what is wrong with just printing the arrays row by row like this:

```
String[] data1 = {"a","b","a","b","a","b","a","b"};
String[] data2 = {"a","a","b","b","a","a","b","b"};
String[] data3 = {"a","a","a","a","b","b","b","b"};
for (int i = 0; i < data1.length; i++) {
  System.out.println(String.format("%s %s %s", data1[i], data2[i], data3[i]));
}
```